# jQuery Form Validation for either/or radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm trying to get an error message to appear if a radio button value is not equal to a specific value. Specifically, I'm trying to provide a series of yes/no questions that, upon submit or onClick of a button, display disclaimers beneath each set of buttons in the event that the value provided is either a) null, or b) not equal to the required value. All of the validation options I've found so far in scouring the interwebs are simple "not null" validation checks, not for a specific value.

I know this isn't a question pertaining to specific code and is more of a functionality question, but any help anyone could be with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you using any validation plugin or using simple javascript?

Comment: I'm using the jquery-validation-plugin as found here: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation

Comment: jsFiddle, if it is of any use... http://jsfiddle.net/2hA8M/181/ Obviously form name isn't right...I'm still just drafting this up.

Comment: I'm thinking that adding an equalTo: 'value' rule might be the way to do it, but it doesn't seem to work in the fiddle...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can write a custom validation method something like this

```
$("#idOfForm").validate({
    rules: {
        agerequirement : {
            radiocheckyes : true
        },
        areyoutheinventor : {
            radiocheckyes : true
        }
    }
});

$.validator.addMethod("radiocheckyes", function(value, element) {
    return (this.optional(element) || $(element).attr("checked"));
}, "Please select");
```

Please note that it wont work if yes is the second element in the radio button group using this code, you need to change the custom validation method as required